# Efficiently combine masks in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

As part of my calculation I end up with 2 masks stored in 2 uint32x4_t variables. These came from [VCEQ](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/CIHGAGID.html). For further processing I want to combine these into a single q-reg or d-reg. What's preferred approach in arm neon to do it?

[Simple solution](https://godbolt.org/g/G29W2s):

```
uint16x8_t combineMasks(uint32x4_t mask_lo, uint32x4_t mask_hi)
{
    uint16x4_t lo = vmovn_u32(mask_lo);
    uint16x4_t hi = vmovn_u32(mask_hi);
    return vcombine_u16(lo, hi);
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? In my case I `vand` result mask later on with some values to [find position of a min/max element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683866/find-min-and-position-of-the-min-element-in-uint8x8-t-neon-register).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// aarch32
vuzp.16     mask_lo, mask_hi        // you can use either one.

// aarch64
uzp1        result.8h, mask_lo.8h, mask_hi.8h
```

Another example on the uselessness of `intrinsux`: `vuzp1` won't compile if your targets include `aarch32`. In other words, you have to write both versions in `intrinsux` anyway, if you want the maximum performance.

What's the point of `intrinsux`? It's too much of a headache compared to the brutally simple assembly coding.

Comment: `vuzp.16     mask_lo, mask_hi` won't produce the same result as combineMasks, right?

Comment: @Pavel Just return either low or high, the result is the same as yours.

Comment: regarding asm/intrinsics: I did some neon asm like 10 years ago and couldn't understand how to even use intrinsics, specially back then they were extremely bad. However, nowadays it's much better than it used to be. I'm just trying different stuff experimenting with algorithms  and it just does not make sense for me to deal with pure asm. For final results I'd definitely consider doing that, but at this point I don't need that, especially that intrinsics work pretty well for me.

Comment: Your current test results are very deceiving. Your routines aren't that complex, and they deal with small chunks of data. The flat overheads will make the performance gains by assembly versions look diminishing. 12,960,000 4x4 complex float matrix multiplications are almost twice as fast when written in assembly, to give you an idea.

Comment: I posted trimmed down simplified versions of code that deal mostly with final/tail results and I'm experimenting with that to see if and how much I can improve stuff.

Comment: I verified and results match, thanks. I find it quite confusing that vuzpq_u16 takes two q regs and returns two q-regs while [according to arm.com](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489f/CIHCACAB.html) it takes one d- or q-reg. I guess both inputs to vuzp are modified in-place, then it makes sense